# Airflow: can a subdag be run inside another subdag?

Tags: airflow

I have a subdag as one of the nodes of a main DAG. The workflow works fine.

I tried to increase the levels of hierarchy by including another subdag inside the subdag. But airflow seem to get confused. Couple of questions in this regard:

1) Does airflow support subdag inside a subdag? If so, is there a limit to the hierarchy?

2) Are there any best practices in using a subdag inside a subdag?

Answer (score 3):

I have recently started using Airflow myself and Airflow does indeed support having subdags inside subdags. I was able to go upto 4 levels deep but I'm not sure as to the exact limit of the hierarchy. Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you please share how you achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

short answer yes you can.
I managed to achieve this by using subdag create  functions following https://github.com/geosolutions-it/evo-odas/wiki/Airflow---about-subDAGs,-branching-and-xcom
I Achieved 3 levels of subdag hierarchy.
Trick is to be extremely careful to follow the maindag.subdag notation in your tasks.

```
task = SubDagOperator(
    subdag=create_subdag(dag_name, task_id, datetime(2019, 1, 29) , None),
    task_id=task_id,
    dag=dag
    )
```

And in the create_subdag function you need to work carefully with the parent and child dags names, nesting several such functions does the job.
You'll see the errors in the UI if any. 
I will update this post with more code if needed but it really depends on how many levels you need so you design the functions like that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started experimenting with subdags. I don't think there is a limit on how deep they can go. A lot of webpages suggest to stay away from subdags because of the issue with connection pools.

I made an example [here](https://gist.github.com/semihsezer/87bdd6991415d883e37c8040f08d2238) with 2 levels. It can be refactored further but it demonstrates the point.

1) Create a helper method to create dags with subdag names formatted as parent.child.

```
def create_sub_dag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, start_date, schedule_interval):
  ''''Returns a DAG which has the dag_id formatted as parent.child '''
  return DAG(
    dag_id='{}.{}'.format(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
    start_date=start_date,
    max_active_runs=15
  )
```

2) Then recursively create and assign subdags to parent dags. Remember, subdags are still DAGs. SubDagOperator only bundles it as a task for the parent dag.

```
level1_list = ['AWS', 'AZURE']
level2_list = ['eu', 'us', 'ap', 'jp']
tasks = ['task_{}'.format(str(i)) for i in range(0, 10)]

for level1_item in level1_list:
    level1_dag = create_sub_dag(dag_id, level1_item, datetime(2020, 3, 10), '0 6 * * *')
    level1_subdag_operator = SubDagOperator(
      subdag=level1_dag,
      task_id=level1_item,
      dag=dag,
    )

    level1_dag_id = '{}.{}'.format(dag_id, level1_item)
    for level2_item in level2_list:
        level2_dag = create_sub_dag(level1_dag_id, level2_item, datetime(2020, 3, 10), '0 6 * * *')
        level2_subdag_operator = SubDagOperator(
          subdag=level2_dag,
          task_id=level2_item,
          dag=level1_dag,
        )
        level2_dag_id = '{}.{}.{}'.format(dag_id, level1_item, level2_item)
        create_tasks(level2_dag, tasks)
```